# Azure DevOps: policy for branch creation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-repos

We want only some people to be able to create 'release/*' branch in Azure DevOps cloud(?) repo.

Unfortunately, I couldn’t find this option in UI.
I also couldn’t find it here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops
and here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops

I tried to implement it with REST API but my attempts were unsuccessful.
I also didn’t find any extension which could help me with this.

I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: Have you reviewed this already?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/require-branch-folders?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Comment: Hi @Alexandr Tymoschuk. I am afraid it is not supported to set branch security by Rest api yet. You can vote it up on this [user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365711/set-branch-security-by-rest-api.html). You might have to use `tf git permission command` as workaround. See below answer

Answer (score 2):

There is not option in the UI to set the `create branch` permission for branches.

However, you can achieve this by runing `tf git permission` commands in `Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio` to deny the permission to create branches under releases. See below example:

Below command will block the users in Contributors group creating branches under releases

```
tf git permission /deny:CreateBranch /group:[MyProject]\Contributors /collection:https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganiza/ /teamproject:MyProject /repository:myRepo /branch:releases
```

Check [Git Permission Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/git-permission-command?view=azure-devops) for more information.

Comment: Isn't `tf git permission` only for on-prem?

Comment: @kagarlickij I tested.  it worked for cloud azure devops too.

Comment: I'ts not my question, I just edited it so can't mark an answer